# Python performance improvements and coding style

Tags: python, performance, pandas

**Question**

Let's assume the following sparse table is given indicating the listing of a security on an index.

```
identifier    from        thru
AAPL          1964-03-31  --
ABT           1999-01-03  2003-12-31
ABT           2005-12-31  --
AEP           1992-01-15  2017-08-31
KO            2014-12-31  --
```

ABT for example is on index from *1999-01-03* to *2003-12-31* and again from *2005-12-31* until *today* (-- indicates today). During times in between it is not listed on index.

How can I efficiently transform this sparse table to a dense table of the following form

```
date          AAPL  ABT  AEP  KO
1964-03-31     1     0    0    0
1964-04-01     1     0    0    0
...           ...   ...  ...  ...
1999-01-03     1     1    1    0
1999-01-04     1     1    1    0
...           ...   ...  ...  ...
2003-12-31     1     1    1    0
2004-01-01     1     0    1    0
...           ...   ...  ...  ...
2017-09-04     1     1    0    1
```

In the section **My Solution** you will find my solution to the problem. Unfortunately, the code seems to perform very bad. It took about 22 seconds to process 1648 entries.

As I am new to python I wondered how to efficiently program problems like these.

I do not intend that anyone is providing me with a solution to my problem (unless you wish to do so). My primary goal would be to understand how to efficiently solve problems like these in python. I used the functionalities of pandas to match the respective entries. Should I have used numpy and indexing instead? Should I have used other toolboxes? How can I gain performance improvements?

Please find my approach to this problem in the section below (if it is of interest to you).

Thank you very much for your help

---

**My Solution**

I have tried to resolve the problem by looping through every row entry in the first table. During every single loop, I specify a Boolean matrix for the specific *from-thru*-interval with all elements set to True. This matrix is appended to a list. At the end, I pd.concat the list and unstack and reindex the resulting DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_ts_data(data, start_date, end_date, attribute=None, identifier=None, frequency=None):
    """
    Transform sparse table to dense table.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data: pd.DataFrame
        sparse table with minimal column specification ['identifier', 'from', 'thru'
    start_date: pd.Timestamp, str
        start date of the dense matrix
    end_date: pd.Timestamp, str
        end date of the dense matrix
    attribute: str
        column name of the value of the dense matrix.
    identifier: str
        column name of the identifier
    frequency: str
        frequency of the dense matrix
    kwargs:
        Allows to overwrite naming of 'from' and 'thru' variables.

        e.g.

        {'from': 'start', 'thru': 'end'}

    Returns
    -------

    """

    if attribute is None:
        attribute = ['on_index']
    elif not isinstance(attribute, list):
        attribute = [attribute]

    if identifier is None:
        identifier = ['identifier']
    elif not isinstance(identifier, list):
        identifier = [identifier]

    if frequency is None:
        frequency = 'B'

    # copy data for security reasons
    data_mod = data.copy()
    data_mod['on_index'] = True

    # specify start date and check type
    if not isinstance(start_date, pd.Timestamp):
        start_date = pd.Timestamp(start_date)

    # specify end date and check type
    if not isinstance(end_date, pd.Timestamp):
        end_date = pd.Timestamp(end_date)

    # specify output date range
    date_range = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=frequency)

    #overwrite null indicating that it is valid until today
    missing = data_mod['thru'].isnull()
    data_mod.loc[missing, 'thru'] = data_mod.loc[missing, 'from'].apply(lambda d: max(d, end_date))

    # preallocate frms
    frms = []

    # add dataframe to frms with time specific entries
    for index, row in data_mod.iterrows():
        # date range index
        d_range = pd.date_range(row['from'], row['thru'], freq=frequency)

        # Multi index with date and identifier
        d_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([d_range] + [[x] for x in row[identifier]], names=['date'] + identifier)

        # add DataFrame with repeated values to list
        frms.append(pd.DataFrame(data=np.repeat(row[attribute].values, d_index.size), index=d_index, columns=attribute))

    out_frame = pd.concat(frms)
    out_frame = out_frame.unstack(identifier)
    out_frame = out_frame.reindex(date_range)

    return out_frame

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = pd.DataFrame({'identifier': ['AAPL', 'ABT', 'ABT', 'AEP', 'KO'],
                         'from': [pd.Timestamp('1964-03-31'),
                                  pd.Timestamp('1999-01-03'),
                                  pd.Timestamp('2005-12-31'),
                                  pd.Timestamp('1992-01-15'),
                                  pd.Timestamp('2014-12-31')],
                         'thru': [np.nan,
                                  pd.Timestamp('2003-12-31'),
                                  np.nan,
                                  pd.Timestamp('2017-08-31'),
                                  np.nan]
                         })

    transformed_data = get_ts_data(data, start_date='1964-03-31', end_date='2017-09-04', attribute='on_index', identifier='identifier', frequency='B')
    print(transformed_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Ensure dates are Pandas timestamps.
df['from'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['from'])
df['thru'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['thru'].replace('--', np.nan))

# Get sorted list of all unique dates and create index for full range.
dates = sorted(set(df['from'].tolist() + df['thru'].dropna().tolist()))
dti = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=dates[0], end=dates[-1], freq='B')

# Create new target dataframe based on symbols and full date range.  Initialize to zero.
df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=df['identifier'].unique(), index=dti)

# Find all active symbols and set their symbols' values to one from their respective `from` dates.
for _, row in df[df['thru'].isnull()].iterrows():
    df2.loc[df2.index >= row['from'], row['identifier']] = 1

# Find all other symbols and set their symbols' values to one between their respective `from` and `thru` dates.
for _, row in df[df['thru'].notnull()].iterrows():
    df2.loc[(df2.index >= row['from']) & (df2.index <= row['thru']), row['identifier']] = 1

>>> df2.head(3)
            AAPL  ABT  AEP  KO
1964-03-31     1    0    0   0
1964-04-01     1    0    0   0
1964-04-02     1    0    0   0

>>> df2.tail(3)
            AAPL  ABT  AEP  KO
2017-08-29     1    1    1   1
2017-08-30     1    1    1   1
2017-08-31     1    1    1   1

>>> df2.loc[:'2004-01-02', 'ABT'].tail()
2003-12-29    1
2003-12-30    1
2003-12-31    1
2004-01-01    0
2004-01-02    0
Freq: B, Name: ABT, dtype: int64

>>> df2.loc['2005-12-30':, 'ABT'].head(3)
2005-12-30    0
2006-01-02    1
2006-01-03    1
Freq: B, Name: ABT, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. I appreciate it. That's pretty neat. Your solution is about 76 times faster in my sample.